# How to execute URL on Fragment change in android?

Tags: android

I have a fragment in my app named"A" and "B" in A fragment I execute URL that fetch data from server when I change to "B" It still loading data.what I want when I change to "B" A stop executing URL when I again switch to A then A start executing.How can I do that.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    m_Main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deal_listing, container, false);//intialize mainLayout
    getDetails();// get deatisl of user from sharedpreference......
    init();//initialize metho
    return m_Main;
}

private void getDetails() {
    CLoginSessionManagement m_oSessionManagement = new CLoginSessionManagement(getActivity());
    HashMap<String, String> user = m_oSessionManagement.getLoginDetails();
    m_szMobileNumber = user.get(CLoginSessionManagement.s_szKEY_MOBILE).trim();// getting password from saved preferences..........
    m_szEncryptedPassword = user.get(CLoginSessionManagement.s_szKEY_PASSWORD).trim();// getting mobile num from shared preferences...
    s_oDataset = new ArrayList<>();

    m_ProgressView = (CircularProgressView) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.progress_view);
    m_ProgressView.startAnimation();
    m_ProgressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    new CDealDataSent().execute(m_DealListingURL);
}
private String DealListing(String url) {
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        String json;
        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("agentCode", m_szMobileNumber);
        jsonObject.put("pin", m_szEncryptedPassword);
        jsonObject.put("recordcount", sz_RecordCount);
        jsonObject.put("lastcountvalue", sz_LastCount);
        //jsonObject.put("emailId", "nirajk1190@gmail.com");
        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();
        System.out.println("Jsons:-" + json);
        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        System.out.println("InputStream....:" + inputStream.toString());
        System.out.println("Response....:" + httpResponse.toString());

        StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
        System.out.println("statusLine......:" + statusLine.toString());
        ////Log.d("resp_body", resp_body.toString());
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            s_szresult = CJsonsResponse.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            //String resp_body =
        } else
            s_szresult = "Did not work!";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("resul.....:" + s_szresult);
    System.out.println("pin:" + m_szEncryptedPassword);
    System.out.println("recordCount:" + sz_RecordCount);
    System.out.println("LastCount:" + sz_LastCount);
    // 11. return s_szResult
    return s_szresult;
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
private void getResponse() throws JSONException {// getting response from serevr ..................
    if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Transaction Successful")) {// server based condition


    } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Connection Not Available")) {//server based conditions
        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection Lost !", getActivity());
    } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Deal List Not Found")) {// serevr based conditions .....
        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No more deals available", getActivity());

    }
}

//  sending deal data to server and retreive response......
class CDealDataSent extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public CDealAppDatastorage item;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        m_ProgressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return DealListing(urls[0]);// sending data to server...

    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {

        m_ProgressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        try {
            m_oResponseobject = new JSONObject(result);// getting response from server
            JSONArray posts = m_oResponseobject.optJSONArray("dealList");


            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                item = new CDealAppDatastorage();
                item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));
                item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));
                item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));
                item.setM_n_Image(m_n_FormImage[i]);
                s_oDataset.add(item);

            }

            // LoadMore button
            Button btnLoadMore = new Button(getActivity());
            btnLoadMore.setText("LOAD MORE DEALS");
            btnLoadMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_boarder);
            btnLoadMore.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Small);
            btnLoadMore.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            btnLoadMore.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            if (!s_oDataset.isEmpty()) {
                // Adding Load More button to lisview at bottom
                m_ListView.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
                m_oAdapter = new CDealAppListingAdapter(getActivity(), s_oDataset);// create adapter object and add arraylist to adapter
                m_ListView.setAdapter(m_oAdapter);//adding adapter to recyclerview
                m_oAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


            btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    m_n_DefaultRecordCount = m_n_DefaultRecordCount + 5;// increment of record count by 5 on next load data
                    m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount + 5;// same here.....as above

                    sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// convert int value to string
                    sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// convert int value to string /////
                    new DealNext(getActivity()).execute(m_DealListingURL);// POST DATA TO SERVER TO LOAD MORE DATA......
                }
            });

            getResponse();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
public class CDealMainListing extends Fragment {
// --Commented out by Inspection (11-04-2016 10:45):public LinearLayout m_MainLayout;
private ViewPager m_ViewPager;
private View m_Main;

@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    m_Main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deals_main_screen, container, false);
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
    init();
    return m_Main;
}

private void init() {
    TabLayout m_TabLayout = (TabLayout) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    m_TabLayout.addTab(m_TabLayout.newTab().setText("Deals"));
    m_TabLayout.addTab(m_TabLayout.newTab().setText("Stories"));
    m_TabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);// setting Gravity of Tab

    m_ViewPager = (ViewPager) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.pager);//finding Id of ViewPager
    CDealMainListingPager m_oDealMainScreenPager = new CDealMainListingPager
            (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), m_TabLayout.getTabCount());
    m_ViewPager.setAdapter(m_oDealMainScreenPager);// adiing adapter to ViewPager
    m_ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(m_TabLayout));// performing action of page changing
    m_TabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            m_ViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: While replacing the From A to B just cancel the network Request

Comment: how do you fetch from network can you post ?

Comment: There are number of ways it can be done

Comment: get the reference of Your http client and try with there two functions after replacing the A fragment wit  Fragment B

Comment: Can you show me from where you are switching between fragments ?

Comment: yes see my edit code

Answer (score 0):

```
private HttpClient httpclient;
private shutDownClient(){
 httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown()
 }
```

use this method when you are switching b/w fragments

Comment: pls giive me proper in which method of A and B I can right and

Comment: in whcih I write A or B

Comment: just add this method and make global variable as 
private HttpClient httpclient; and then while replacing or adding the fragment use that method it will shut down your Httpclient